# code that gives different values on different online compilers

Tags: c

I have a code that gives different values on different online compilers, I am new to C programming, please let me know if different values are expected while we run the following code on different c online compilers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct hai
{
    char c;
    long l;
    char *p;
};
union bye
{
    char c;
    long l;
    char *p;
};
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct hai myhai;
    union bye mybye;
    myhai.c = 1;
    myhai.l = 2L;
    myhai.p = "This is myhai";
    mybye.c = 1;
    mybye.l = 2L;
    mybye.p = "This is mybye";
    printf("myhai: %d %ld %s\n", myhai.c, myhai.l, myhai.p);
    printf("mybye: %d %ld %s\n", mybye.c, mybye.l, mybye.p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The standard says that reading from any element in a union other than the last one written is undefined behavior.

Comment: Your union fields are being overwritten by your character pointer, so of course that's non-portable.  The aliased integer fields are printing whatever happens to be in the corresponding portion of the pointer.  That's highly non-portable.

Comment: @kaylum in C++. in C it is not UB

Comment: Why did you use the union in the first place? Did you read what they are good for?

Answer (score 2):

Union is the place where members share the same memory location. Union has only storage enough for the largest member of it.

Writing any of members overwrites at least the part of the memory occupies by other members.

In your case the at write is important. It stores the address of the string literal into the union. When you read the `c` member you read the first byte of this address.

Answer (score 0):

In a union the fields are overlayed. Exactly how is undefined:

- Little endian and big endian play a role, both can have the fields aligned at offset 0, but other byte values reside there. (LE = least significant byte first: 257 = 02 01; BE = most signifact byte first: 257= 01 02
- The struct is not zeroed, so after assigning a char, the long will contain rubish, and the char likely is the least or most significant byte.

Comment: Not undefined only defined implementation defined way

Comment: @0___________ a fine distinction, hence one advise: read the implementation definitions,

Comment: union punning is one of the safe (but implementation-defined) ways of type punning. The behavior is **not** undefined. In C++ it is undefined. In C is not undefined.

Comment: from C standard: `if the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the
object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new
type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called "type punning"). This might be a trap representation.`

Comment: @0___________ and there I thought C++ was always better. Thanks for this piece of insight.

Comment: You welcome :). I do not find it better. IMO both languages are very good for different kinds of tasks. I personally use C for very low lever hardware related programming (and do not care too much about portability) and C++ to wirte "normal" applications.

Comment: @0___________ the Linus also made a point in favor of C for Linux (on OS level).